# Property 'then' does not exist on type Observable<QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>>

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
db.collection("cities").get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
```

I'm trying to read multiple document of a collection, but getting error on then.
Please help me to sort out this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to treat is as a promise, you can convert it to a promise. This isn't a hack, once there's only one emission being produced by `get()`. But Firebase expected you to deal with the stream that's coming out from `get()` though. Anyway, to convert it to a promise:

```js
db.collection("cities").get().toPromise()
  .then((querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
```

If you decide to deal with the streaming coming out from `get()`, as Firebase API expected you to:

```js
db.collection("cities").get()
  .subscribe((querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
```

[UPDATE] 1: Based on the docs, there's a new API for getting the snapshots, using the `onSnapshot` method:

```js
db.collection("cities")
  .onSnapshot((querySnapshot: QuerySnapshot<DocumentData>) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc: any) => {
      // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
  });
```

Comment: Hello, subscribe here is deprecated, what should I use? thank you

Comment: From the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), you can try the `onSnapshot` method. It exists in the `CollectionReference`, which is the above case for the `db.collection('cities')` and for a single `DocumentReference` inside the collection, like we have in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) examples.